# maven error with build all argument

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am a beginner in maven. I have just installed maven 3.3.1.
I have already added the m2_Home pointing to the installation directory in the environment variable.

I created a quick demo project for testing purposes named tutorialsJava.
In my eclipse, I have configured the external tools  configuration for different maven arguments

for e.g I am using the build-all argument

[image]

Here when I run the project using the maven Build all command, I have the following error.
[image]

I have tried several solutions on the web like changing the arguments in the path
I have also tried with this solution but without any success.

[image]
Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: does `mvn` command work for you when you try it from a command prompt window?

Comment: maybe there is an `mvn.bat` that you need to use, instead of `mvn`

Comment: There is no mvn.bat, only mvn file. it works fine from the command line. The only issue is with the eclipse using external configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use M2Ecilpse which is a Maven integration for Eclipse: http://eclipse.org/m2e/